How can I have multiple jax-rs jars in a wildfly .ear without conflicting?
I have several projects in a .ear with front in war, and server .jar in ejb, I'm testing implementation of jax-rs for rest, the problem is that it's giving conflict in the urls, w also the endpoint path has to go through a war for example the same endpoint can be watched by: http://localhost:8180/MyExec/warone/projectone/api/zip?zip=12345678 and by http://localhost:8180/MyExec/wartwo/projectone/api/zip?zip=12345678 o and if you have an equal endpoint like the /zip in different conflicts  ex:
http://localhost:8180/MyExec/warone/projectone/api/zip?zip=12345678 and by http://localhost:8180/MyExec/warone/projecttwo/api/zip?zip=12345678
projetctone application @ApplicationPath("/projectone/api/") public class RestApplication extends Application { }
projecttwo @ApplicationPath("/projecttwo/api") public class RestApplication extends Application { }
I would like to be able to use several projects .jar jax-rs and be able to map correctly without conflict

Are your REST applications packaged in different WAR's or the same WAR?
